# Devise Passwords Controller JSON params not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I'm trying to hit the Devise PasswordsController using JSON. I've overriden the controller to respond to JSON.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  respond_to :json
end
```

I'm passing the params via JSON (using Postman) with the Content-Type = application/json. I'm trying to POST to `/users/password`. The params look like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "me@domain.com"       
  }
}
```

Which should be correct, but each time I get an HTTP 422 error.

```
{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"]}}
```

I've also tried my JSON like this:

```
{
  "user[email]": "me@domain.com" 
}
```

Still no luck.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: post data JSON syntax is valid, there might be mismatch between expected post data and actual sent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that I was passing Content-Type="application/json" to the service in quotes in Postman (like shown), this caused the controller to get all confused and not accept the parameters, hence the error message.